How can background.js send an XHR to a server in the context of a Chrome extension?
I want to build an extension that requires sending a message to a node.js server and receiving a response. It should do this automatically, which is why I can't implement this in popup.js. This is my extension-side code that sends a message to the server:
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/data', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response.response);
    }
};
const message = { message: 'Hello' };
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(message));

And this is my server-side code for receiving an answer and replying:
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/data') {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        const receivedMessage = JSON.parse(body).message;
        console.log('Received message: ${receivedMessage}');
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ response: 'Server received: ${receivedMessage}' }));
    });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Not Found');
    }
});

This code works when I run it through the popup.js script. When I run this through the content.js script though, it gets blocked by CORS policy ("Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."). I found out that there is no way to bypass CORS, and therefore think it is best to run it via background.js. But then I get a reference error: 'ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined'.
I assume that this is caused by XMLHttpRequest not being built-in. There should be ways to find workarounds using npm modules, but I often read that one should be careful doing so. This is why I want to ask if there is an conceptually easier way or if I did not understand something correctly. Thanks!

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/to-service-workers#replace-xmlhttprequest

You should try making a request from your background-script.

And yes, as @Thomas Mueller said, use fetch. That can also be useful.

@SerhiiFomenko Thank you very much! I use fetch() now from the background script and it works well. However, I encounter now the problem that fetch is asynchronous and I run into issues now when I try to pass the fetch response back to content.js. Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Thank you!

@ThomasMueller Thank you! I use fetch() now and it works perfectly fine, that helped me a lot!

Yes, it's not hard to do. I wouldn't want to give a full-fledged answer to this. But if you want to keep it short, just replace all your code with this - fetch('http://localhost:3000/data', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(message),  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}}).then(response => response.text()).then(textData => console.log(JSON.parse(textData)))

And to send it back to the content script, replace this line .then(textData => console.log(JSON.parse(textData))) with this line .then(textData => sendResponse(JSON.parse(textData))), don't forget to return true in the listener.

@SerhiiFomenko Haha you're my hero, that worked perfectly. Thank you! I tried this actually earlier but used it without returning true in the listener

For sending requests automatically from the background in Manifest V3, it is recommended to use chrome.alarms
background.js:
await chrome.alarms.create("your_alarm_name", {periodInMinutes: 0.5})
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarmCallback)

// your request logic
function alarmCallback() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/data', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(response.response);
        }
    };
    const message = { message: 'Hello' };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
    xhr.send()
}

That's it! This is how you can send requests automatically in the background.
But as I understand, you also need a way to use this data in the content script. You can do this using chrome.storage
background.js:
async function alarmCallback() {
    ...
    // Save your response to the extension's local storage
    await chrome.storage.local.set({xhrResponse: response})
}

And then you can access your xhrResponse using the following code:
contentScript.js:
// Content scripts have access to your extension's local storage too
const xhrResponse = await chrome.storage.local.get("xhrResponse")

